# Out Of Range but it is in range?

Tags: c#

So I want to learn the periodic table but I want to program a game to do it (It will be a console window). So the first code is the class for an element, its pretty easy...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PeriodicTableGame
{
    class Element
    {
        int AtomicNumber;
        double AtomicMass;
        string Name;
        int Period;
        int Group;
        bool isLanthanide;
        bool isActanide;
        int isMetal; // 0 = Non Metal, 1 = Metaloid, 2 = Metal
        int stateAtRT; // 0 = Solid, 1 = Liquid, 2 = Gas, 3 = Plasma (68     Degrees F, 20 Celcius, 293.15 Kelvin)

        int Block; // 0 = s, 1 = d, 2 = p, 3 = f

        public Element(int atomicNumber, double atomicMass, int period, int group, bool islanthanide, bool isactanide, int ismetal, int stateatrt, int block)
        {
            AtomicNumber = atomicNumber;
            AtomicMass = atomicMass;
            Period = period;
            Group = group;
            isLanthanide = islanthanide;
            isActanide = isactanide;
            isMetal = ismetal;
            stateAtRT = stateatrt;
            Block = block;
        }
    }
```

So that block is good so far, and now the second block...

```
class Data
{
    public static List<Element> ElementList = new List<Element>();

    public static List<Element> AddToList()
    {
        Element Nothing = new Element(0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, 0, 0, 0);
        Element Hydrogen = new Element(1, 1.008, 1, 1, false, false, 0, 2, 0);
        Element Helium = new Element(2, 4.003, 1, 18, false, false, 0, 2, 0);
        Element Lithium = new Element(3, 6.94, 2, 1, false, false, 0, 0, 0);
        Element Beryllium = new Element(4, 9.012, 2, 2, false, false, 2, 0, 0);
        Element Boron = new Element(5, 10.81, 2, 13, false, false, 1, 0, 2);
        Element Test = new Element(0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, 0, 0, 0);
        ElementList.Insert(0, Nothing);
        ElementList.Insert(1, Hydrogen);
        ElementList.Insert(2, Helium);
        ElementList.Insert(3, Lithium);
        ElementList.Insert(4, Beryllium);
        ElementList.Insert(5, Boron);
        ElementList.Insert(6, Test);
        return ElementList;
    }
}
```

That one is also good, and now the 3rd block...

```
class NumberGenerator
{
    public static int RandomNumberGenerator(int Min, int Max)
    {
        Random RandomGen = new Random();
        int RandomGenChoice = RandomGen.Next(Min, Max + 1);
        return RandomGenChoice;
    }
    public static Element RandomElementGenerator(int Number)
    {
        Element x = Data.ElementList.ElementAt(Number);
        return x;
    }
}

    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int RNG = NumberGenerator.RandomNumberGenerator(1, 5);
        Element y = NumberGenerator.RandomElementGenerator(RNG);
    }
```

(Ignore the brackets I may have missed one on this post but they are fine in Visual Studio) I made a list of elements (I started with 5, and a 1st, and a test...) and tries to use the ElementGenerator on them but it gave an out of range exception, so I used an array, which is what you are looking at, and than I use the number 1 instead of 'Number' which is an Index no question, I put it in by hand, and I still got an out of range exception... WHY?

Comment: That's a lot of code to read through.  Perhaps you might add a `<--- exception here` to the problem line?

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger and tell us which line you notice things going off the rails.

Comment: I will! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: how do I edit the question?

Comment: its in the last section I posted on the 13th line down (from the class # Generator)

Comment: Specifically this...

Comment: Element x = ElementListArray[Number];

Comment: I don't see a call to `AddToList`, but if you stepped through the code line by line, you would be able to see what `Data.ElementList` contained when the code runs.

Comment: I used the code ElementList.Insert(ElementName,Index);, thats the way I saw how to use lists, maybe i'm wrong

Comment: ElementList.Insert(0, Nothing);
        ElementList.Insert(1, Hydrogen);
        ElementList.Insert(2, Helium);
        ElementList.Insert(3, Lithium);
        ElementList.Insert(4, Beryllium);
        ElementList.Insert(5, Boron);
        ElementList.Insert(6, Test);

Comment: Read what crashmastr is saying. You forgot to call AddToList().

Comment: BTW the easier way is to use Add for lists.

Comment: I thought AddToList() was the same as Elementlist.Index(Name,Index) but the second one indexes at a specific number, is that wrong? and do i add first or index first?

Comment: So I should not add 1, I was thinking it would make up for the exclusivity of the last number in the Random class, ill try removing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you post this code to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), because there are several things you could do more easily using C# features.

But going with the problem as it is...

```
Element y = NumberGenerator.RandomElementGenerator(i);
```

Are you sure this line is typed here as it is in your code?  Because I could understand the error if it were really this:

```
Element y = NumberGenerator.RandomElementGenerator(j);  // j, not i
```

Here is what your `Main` method is doing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // generate random number from 1 to 5
    int i = NumberGenerator.RandomNumberGenerator(5, 1);

    // print the number
    Console.WriteLine(i);

    // set j equal to (1 to 5) - 7 + 1 = (-6 to -1) [but this line is unused]
    int j = i - Data.ElementList.Count + 1;

    // Get an element in position -6 to -1
    Element y = NumberGenerator.RandomElementGenerator(j);

    // Wait for user to press a key
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If that fourth line is `j` as I believe, then you're trying to get the element at a position from -1 to -6, but an array will only have 0 and positive number positions.

You can use your debugger to find out what `Number` contains.  When you get the exception, hover over `Number` to see what value it has.  In Visual Studio 2017, it might show you this value automatically anyhow.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even realize that I was searching for negative numbers, IDK how I didn't see it... Thank you so much!

Comment: @rancorjoy, if this answer helped, you can indicate that by clicking the checkmark to confirm it as the answer, and also by clicking the up arrow to vote for it.  And if you post the code to Code Review, you might consider adding a link to that here.

Comment: class NumberGenerator
    {
        public static int RandomNumberGenerator(int Min, int Max)
        {
            Random RandomGen = new Random();
            int RandomGenChoice = RandomGen.Next(Min, Max + 1);
            return RandomGenChoice;
        }
        public static Element RandomElementGenerator(int Number)
        {
            Element x = Data.ElementList.ElementAt(Number);
            return x;
        }
    }

Comment: class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int RNG = NumberGenerator.RandomNumberGenerator(1, 5);
            Element y = NumberGenerator.RandomElementGenerator(RNG);
        }

Comment: I changed it so that all those comments you made were fixed (I thought) but it still fails...

Comment: @rancorjoy At the same place?  Have you used your debugger to inspect the values of variables?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an empty list. 
Add items your **Data.ElementList** via **Data.AddToList()** first before calling the index.

```
    public static Element RandomElementGenerator(int Number)
    {
        Data.AddToList();
        Element x = Data.ElementList.ElementAt(Number);
        return x;
    }
```

Then you can call the index in the **Data.ElementList**.